# Add swagger doc to Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Sorry if my question is quite bad. But could you tell me:
I wrote swagger documentation first throught yaml format.  Then I created java classes based on it. I did it by my hand, not generate them. Maybe it's important.
And now I want to connect my swaggerAPI and my Spring Boot application. All the information that I found said that I need to write annotation and etc. But I've already had swaggerApi, have an application and want to interact between them.

Can I do it or not? Or could you tell me what I need to do.

Here is a public link to swaggerHub:

```
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/SAPOGHNIK23_1/Bank_account_public/1.0.0
```